# Electron builder extraResources has no effect

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

Build options for electron-builder look like this:

```
"build": {
  "productName": "BCTool",
  "appId": "scripter.BCTool",
  "extraResources": [
    {
      "from": "./vbs/",
      "to": "vbs/",
      "filter": [
        "**/*"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "nsis": {
    "guid": "835d29d9-59bf-4106-85db-df02efea251e",
    "oneClick": false,
    "perMachine": true
  },
  "win": {
    "target": "nsis",
    "icon": "icon.ico",
    "requestedExecutionLevel": "requireAdministrator"
  },
  "directories": {
    "app": "./"
  }
}
```

What I am expecting is a folder 'vbs' with files in it which is located inside the win-unpacked/resources folder. However there is none. The vbs folder is located in root folder. I assume I do everything correctly, if not, please correct me. Is this some kind of problem with electron-builder??